# Strategy close pinescript

Tags: pine-script

For some reason, the profit-and-loss (P&L) doesn't calculate at `buyclose`; instead, it takes the P&L between buy and sell order. I want the trade to close when the `buyclose` criteria are met and calculate P&L.

```
buy = (close> s) and (close > s2)
buyclose = (close < s) or (close < s2)
if (buy)
    strategy.entry("buy", long=true, when=buy)
    strategy.close("buy",when=buyclose)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, visit the site below to know [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

In your case the `if` operator is redundant.

```
buy = (close> s) and (close>s2)
buyclose = (close<s) or (close<s2)

strategy.entry("buy", long=true, when=buy)
strategy.close("buy", when=buyclose)
```